# How does angular application access a database through a local server?

Tags: mysql, database, angular, tomcat

We are working on building an application where the technologies used are Angular( for front-end), Spring boot(for middle-layer) and MySQL database(for back-end). Right now, the front-end directly calls the Apache tomcat server to access the database. This, however, is not secure. To be more secure, I was told that we need to have a setup where the front-end calls the local setup(server) for data and the local server calls the actual server.

As I could not get enough information regarding this, can anyone suggest/explain about how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Angular HTTPClient to send requests to my endpoints in spring.  I'd use Spring MVC or Jersey with Spring Boot to establish endpoints for my frontend to hit.  You could pass an Authorization key in the header to be checked in Spring or you could use an api management solution like ibm's apiconnect or any competitors to further secure the endpoints.  Hope this gives you some ideas to look into.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please suggest links providing further information.